# How Angular keeps data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I've got an Angular app which has a tab system which means I can have multiple forms opened at the same time and I navigate through them via tabs.

For achieving this I have a special array with tabs and for these tabs I create my forms via

```
<form-component *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" [id]="tab.obj.id"
[class.d-none]="!tab.active">
</form-component>
```

The question is why when I'm removing a tab via `tabs.splice(i, 1)` forms that have been created do not lose their values?

I've been thinking that when an array changes Angular does re-render everything thus I'd had to lose all the data, but it's hold (my forms data is saved only in form-component).

Comment: I think its `tabs.splice(i, 1)` not `tab.splice(i, 1)`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez yep. It's typo

Comment: try to reproduce your issue using https://stackblitz.com, and post it here

Comment: Are the formgroups / controls in tab.obj?

Comment: Nope. FormGroups are just created in form-component for each tab. If tab has some Id form retrieves the data from the server

Comment: `tab.obj` is an object with some metadata.